# Sending signed transaction to create a contract

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, contract-deployment, json-rpc, javascript

My goal is to send a signed transaction to create a smart contract, however, I am facing an issue I have not been able to solve for  few days:

When I send the transaction (on a private chain), there are two different ending:

**- 1**
Web3js tells me it worked, I can see the transaction on the block. However, when trying to contact the contract, I have the following output:

> Error: Couldn't decode uint256 from ABI: 0x

When I try to run `eth.getCode(contractAddress)` in Geth, it returns `0x`

**- 2**
Web3js tells me that the transaction has not been mined for 50 blocks (the node did not have time to mine 50 blocks). But I can see the transaction in the block (in geth).

Here is the code I use:

```
web3g = result;
getContractInstance(function (error, instance) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    } else {
        let newContract = instance;
        let deploy = newContract.deploy({
            data: bytecode,
            arguments: [MY ARGS]
        }).encodeABI();
        let gas = web3g.utils.toHex(3000000);
        let gasPrice = web3g.utils.toHex(21000000000);
        let gasLimit = web3g.utils.toHex(4000000);
        let nonce;
        web3g.eth.getTransactionCount(req.body.sender_address)
            .then(function (result) {
                nonce = result;
                nonce = web3g.utils.toHex(nonce);
                let transactionObject = {
                    gas: gas,
                    gasPrice: gasPrice,
                    gasLimit: gasLimit,
                    data: deploy,
                    from: req.body.sender_address,
                    nonce: nonce
                };

                web3g.eth.accounts.signTransaction(transactionObject, req.body.private_key, function (error, signedTx) {
                    if (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    } else {
                        console.log(signedTx);
                        web3g.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedTx.rawTransaction)
                            .on('confirmation', function (number, receipt) {
                                if (number == 1) {
                                        // do stuff
```

Can someone point me out what I am doing wrong?

Note: I am able to send signed transaction using the method above to transfer ether between addresses.

Edit: Estimating gas returns the following: error: Returned error: gas required exceeds allowance or always failing transaction

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar trouble in creating signed transactions and end up developing this package. https://www.npmjs.com/package/web3js-raw. Should solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. however, using an non official library is not an option for me, as this is for professionnal purpose and you migth not keep updating your library. But could you explain what is the problem?

Comment: You do not have to use the library, because the source code is available in public in git repo (https://github.com/fidenz-chim/web3js-raw). There are so many moving parts when you try to sign a transaction. All I have done is package web3.js functions in an easy to use manner to use in sendRawTransaction. If you are happy to share contract, I could deploy it and see what happens.

Comment: I'll check it when I'll be able to. Will come back to you asap!

Comment: Well, your solution seems to be quite good. Will try to implement it on my side. If too much difficulties, will fork it. Thank you!

Comment: Using web3js ^0.17.0 does not allow me to connect to the node: ONNECTION ERROR: Couldn't connect to node. But it works fine with web3js ^1.0.0-beta.26. Sam =e on my own implementation or with yours

Comment: I could confirm web3js ^0.17.0 works without a problem at my end. Works for me and my colleague as well.

Comment: Are you running it against your own node? If yes, what is the version of geth? (i'm on 1.7.3)

Comment: I have been testing with infura.io, so as my colleague.